# Wildfly - The server didn't respond in time

Tags: timeout, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 10 and resteasy implementation.
Communication between 2 jbosses is broken after 200 seconds request
I have defined time-out in web.xml for 30 minutes

```
 Probable cause: * returned an error response with a status: 504 and a response message: <html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
```

The server didn't respond in time.

```
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:455)
```

Could anyone help me to find out where this time-out can be configured in standalone.xml or somewhere else ?
Thanks in advance